# Maven - exec-maven-plugin - Comma separated attributes

Tags: java, maven, glassfish

I use the `exec-maven-plugin` plugin to deploy my war file to GlassFish. 
The Maven build fails because it put commas before every `<attribute>`.

Here are the arguments of the `exec-maven-plugin`:

```xml
<configuration>
    <executable>${my.gf.asadmin}</executable>
    <arguments>
        <argument>-u ${my.gf.username}</argument>
        <argument>-W ${my.gf.password}</argument>
        <argument>-H ${my.gf.host}</argument>
        <argument>-p ${my.gf.port}</argument>
        <argument>deploy</argument>
        <argument>${my.file.url}</argument>
    </arguments>
</configuration>
```

and here is the relevant part of the log:

```
[DEBUG] Toolchains are ignored, 'executable' parameter is set to /usr/local/programs/glassfish4/glassfish/bin/asadmin
[DEBUG] Executing command line: [/usr/local/programs/glassfish4/glassfish/bin/asadmin, -u admin], -W, -H localhost, -p 4848, deploy, /home/akoel/Projects/java/TMP-TEST/hu.akoel.ear/target/maventest-0.0.2.war]
Non-boolean option: u, not allowed in argument: -u admin]
```

You can see the commas before all attributes.
Is there any way to change the commas to space or even nothing?
I'm not sure if it is important that I work on Ubuntu.

Comment: I tried with --user ... as well. I got the same result. Anyway the `asadmin`  says:
    Usage: asadmin [-H|--host <host(default:localhost)>]
        [-p|--port <port(default:4848)>] [-u|--user <user(default:admin)>]
        [-W|--passwordfile <passwordfile>]
        [-t|--terse[=<terse(default:false)>]]
        [-s|--secure[=<secure(default:false)>]]
        [-e|--echo[=<echo(default:false)>]]
        [-I|--interactive[=<interactive(default:true)>]]
        [-?|--help[=<help(default:false)>] 
        [--detach(default:false)] 
        [--notify(default:false)] [subcommand [options] [operands]]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the [`commandLineArgs`](http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/exec-mojo.html#commandlineArgs)-tag and add your arguments to it:

```xml
<commandlineArgs>
    -u ${my.gf.username} -W ${my.gf.password} -H ${my.gf.host} -p ${my.gf.port} deploy ${my.file.url}
</commandlineArgs>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works! 
I got an another answer before this in the comment (probably from Tunaki). It helps as well. His advice was to separate the switch from the parameter. For example: 
`<argument>-u</argument>
<argument>${my.gf.username}</argument>`

Comment: I didn't try that but In my opinion the solution you've mentioned isn't really "readable". Of course properly separated arguments are even better than my solution but to  split the arguments by key and value isn't the right way imho.

Comment: I agree. I just mentioned that though the solution sounded weird it worked. Regarding I spent my all day with this problem without any progress I thought that I should thank him his advice by mentioning. 
Anyway, you helped me a lot. Thanks again.